# Preventing Déjà Dup from attempting a backup when out of my network

Tags: networking, backup, security, deja-dup

I’ve set Déjà Dup to back up daily to my home network’s Synology NAS (by WebDAV, if you’re curious).

The problem is that my laptop comes with me to many places. My laptop does not seem to realise that it is not in my home network, and it tries (and fails ‘loudly’ tossing up windows with error messages *& cetera*) to make a backup.

This is not only silly (the backup process should at least be minimally context-aware), but also a potential security hazard (it is not hard to imagine a malicious user creating a host on a third-party network with the correct IP address to mimic that of my home NAS, and configure it to accept any login credentials whatsoever in order to obtain a fraudulent copy of my whole machine’s backup).

The question therefore is this: is there a way of preventing Déjà Dup from attempting a backup when it is *not sure* it is on my home network? This would seem to be a modest desire. (Then again, from what I read, it lacks even the rudimentary facility for allowing FTP login credentials to be passed, so maybe it’s not yet suitable for anything but the most trivial usage cases.)

Answer (score 2):

If the hostname for your NAS isn't reachable, Déjà Dup knows to wait.  If you are specifying the server by IP, try specifying it by hostname.

And Déjà Dup should use FTP login credentials just fine.  Have you had troubles doing that?

Comment: Nowhere have I found documentation indicating how to format FTP login credentials when setting up a backup from the GUI. Can you point me in the right direction?

As for specifying the hostname of the NAS, my home network does not have a DNS server, so I’m stuck with numbers. I might set one up if I get around to it, but it’s still fairly frail from the security standpoint.

Comment: Just choose FTP as a storage location.  Then when you back up, you will be asked for username/password credentials.

Comment: That didn’t happen. It never did. It just failed complaining that the destination was ‘unavailable’. Server-side logs showed an attempt at anonymous login, rapidly rebuffed.

Comment: Hmm, then maybe there is a bug... :(